# Issues with working with arraylists, listviews and intents

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, arraylist

I'm working on android studio, it's an app that shows data of some vehicles in a list view, the data is stored on an arraylist and is of a class named Vehicle.

On the listview the idea is that is shows the licence plate of the car, color, etc. It works fine, what I need to do is that when you click on an item it sends you to another intent where you can edit the data of the car, here I ran into my problem, how do I tell that intent whose data is it editing?

```
listaVehiculos.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent editar = new Intent(Lista.this,Editar.class);
            //editar.putExtra("Placa",listaVehiculos.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
            editar.putExtra("Codigo",listaVehiculos.getItemIdAtPosition(i));
            editar.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Vehiculos",Vehiculos);
            startActivity(editar);
        }
    });
```

That's the code I have on the view where the listview is, listavehiculos being the listview itself and Vehiculos being the arraylist, what I need is to also send to the other activity is which listview item I selected so it'd know which element of the arraylist to edit.

On the other activity I have this

```
editar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.editar);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final ArrayList<Vehiculo> Vehiculos3 = extras.getParcelableArrayList("Vehiculos");
    dos= extras.getString("Placa");
```

I've been messing around with different putExtra values but I don't know how to return me a position, or anything to tell me which object I selected.

Answer (score 0):

Look [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

When you use `putExtra` , you did not use `Bundle` .So you just `intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("Vehiculos");` and `intent.getStringExtra("Placa");` to get value .

And make sure that `ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value` .

Try

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 final ArrayList<Vehiculo> Vehiculos3 = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("Vehiculos");
 dos= intent.getStringExtra("Placa");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a bundle

Change ,

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
final ArrayList<Vehiculo> Vehiculos3 = extras.getParcelableArrayList("Vehiculos");
dos= extras.getString("Placa");
```

to

```
Intent i = getIntent();
```

`final ArrayList<Vehiculo> Vehiculos3 = i.getParcelableArrayListExtra("Vehiculos");
    dos= i.getStringExtra("Placa");`